# Why do I have missing data sources in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio

I ran into an interesting issue today. When I open my projects in Visual Studio, all of my object binding data sources are no longer being recognized.

Has anyone ran across this, and how have they handled this in the past? I am running Visual Studio 2008 + SP1.

Answer (score 0):

What populates these datasources? A missing .xml or a database which is down, maybe?

Comment: umm... I'm doing an object data source, and I have all the required xml files.  They haven't changed a bit.  need to do more investigation, but thought that someone may have had this issue before, and had a solution to it.